# ajax request isn't submitting to the database after jquery keyup function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make it so that when there is a keyup within the textarea, it will set the "diary" value within the database to "Hola" (for now) for the specified user that is logged in. I am also not alerted that the data is saved either after keyup.

loggedInPage.php

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-group" name="diaryForm" id="diaryForm">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="diary" name="diary"></textarea> 
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#diary").keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "updateDatabase.php",
            data: { content: $("#diary").val() }
            success: function(data)
        });
            .done(function(msg) {
                alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
            }); 

    })

</script>
```

updateDatabase.php

```
<?php

    include("connection.php");

    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `diary` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, "Hello")."' WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['email'])."'";

    mysqli_query($link, $query);


?>
```

Comment: Where's your html? What happens if you type `$("#diary")` in the dev console?

Comment: No "content" variable is being used in the PHP file. Also you have a typo in the code, try this better:

$("#diary").keyup(function () {
 $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "updateDatabase.php",
  data: {
   content: $("#diary").val()
  }
  success: function (data)
 }).done(function (msg) {
  alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
 });
});

Comment: Take a look at your AJAX syntax - make sure the problem doesn't come from there. Start with removing ; before .done(...)

Comment: @JCHernández Does "success" need to be part of a typical ajax syntax?

Comment: Could be, but not always will be sun and shinings in the dev world, so i sugest using ",error: function(){}" too

Answer (score 2):

### Remove the `;` before `.done`

```
...
})
.done(function(msg) {
...
```

### You're missing a comma after:

```
data: { content: $("#diary").val() }
```

### You also have an incomplete `success` option.

`success: function(data)` is not valid. Since you are using `done`, just remove it...like the following

```js
$("#diary").keyup(function() {

  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "updateDatabase.php",
      data: {content: this.value}
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
    })
    .error(function(err){
      console.log(err.statusText)
    })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form class="form-group" name="diaryForm" id="diaryForm">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="diary" name="diary"></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! After removing the semicolon and adding the comma I am still seeing no improvement. This is the html that is relative to this textarea.

    <div class="container-fluid">
            <form class="form-group" name="diaryForm" id="diaryForm">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="diary" name="diary"></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>

Comment: Thank you for adding the code inline Kevin, this is my first ever time using StackOverflow. The keyup does work correctly using that code, but the ajax request seems to be the issue. Upon every keyup, I see in the js console this error: **loggedInPage.php:96 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous> (loggedInPage.php:96)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)**

Comment: Yes, I receive that same error that was posted above.

Comment: If you click "run code snippet" above, the code works (console says error because the ajax page doesn't exist)

Comment: I see how it works there, but for some reason in my console it says that $.ajax is not a function, I don't quite understand that. Try going here [link] (http://79.170.40.172/justingrabenbauer.com/Content/7-mysql/secret-diary-project/) and clicking the "Log In" link at the bottom, enter "npaerials@gmail.com" for the email and "asdf" as the password, then Log In. If you open up the js console and then enter some characters in the textarea, then the error will be shown.

Comment: Ah, yep, that's cause you're using the ["jQuery Slim build"](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/) which doesn't include ajax

Comment: I just read this as well. Haha. Thank you for all of your help Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of jQuery you are using. Because as per the [jQuery Release Document](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/%22jQuery%20Release%20Document%22), **slim version of jQuery excludes ajax and effects**. So, try the compressed or uncompressed version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

$('#diary').bind('input propertychange', function() {

```
            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "updatedatabase.php",
              data: { content: $("#diary").val() }
            })
              .done(function( msg ) {

                alert( "Data saved: " + msg );
              });
```

> Blockquote 
>    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
>
> Blockquote
>    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">

This code works for me but i had to change the script src of both ajax and bootstrap. Had "slim" ajax error and then .done error but fixed with new script src.